# AWS Signature Version 2 - can't reproduce signature from example

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have problem with reproducing signature from this example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html

I am using this page for calculating HMAC-SHA256: (*need to remove link because of limitations*)
In PL/SQL I am getting the same results.

**Inputs**

*String:*
GET\nelasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com\n/\nAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&Action=DescribeJobFlows&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2011-10-03T15%3A19%3A30&Version=2009-03-31

*Secret:* wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

*Result:* c606d8236c5e81560c553be7868a9cf3fa296cdd2fff93e7fbc8bdbac0100239

Result after encoding to Base64: YzYwNmQ4MjM2YzVlODE1NjBjNTUzYmU3ODY4YTljZjNmYTI5NmNkZDJmZmY5M2U3ZmJjOGJkYmFjMDEwMDIzOQ==

Result after URL encoding: YzYwNmQ4MjM2YzVlODE1NjBjNTUzYmU3ODY4YTljZjNmYTI5NmNkZDJmZmY5M2U3ZmJjOGJkYmFjMDEwMDIzOQ%3D%3D

**Expected result:** i91nKc4PWAt0JJIdXwz9HxZCJDdiy6cf%2FMj6vPxyYIs%3D

Do I missing something? Or is my approach wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

I figured it out that on upper page "hexdigest" is calculated instead "digest" which is needed for AWS Signature. Working example in Ruby: https://repl.it/FPwZ/0
I use HMAC-SHA1 instead of HMAC-SHA256, because in PL/SQL I can't calculate HMAC-SHA256.

Now I have a new problem in PL/SQL.
dbms_crypto.mac returns "hexdigest" value instead of "digest" value. Can I get "digest" value in PL/SQL?

*digest* -> binary string, *hexdigest* -> hex encoded string