# AWS Signature Version 2 Example not reproducible

Tags: amazon-web-services, hmac

Like the guy in this question ([AWS Signature Version 2 - can't reproduce signature from example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683711/aws-signature-version-2-cant-reproduce-signature-from-example)) I can't run the example of AWS Signature Version 2 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html).

We have the string:

```
GET\nelasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com\n/\nAWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&Action=DescribeJobFlows&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2011-10-03T15%3A19%3A30&Version=2009-03-31
```

and the sample secret key

```
wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

To be independent of any programming language, lets take an online tool for the hash, which is calculated with HmacSHA256: https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/HMAC/

But I get the following hash value:

```
xgbYI2xegVYMVTvnhoqc8/opbN0v/5Pn+8i9usAQAjk=
```

which is sadly not the expected value (not URL-encoded here):

```
i91nKc4PWAt0JJIdXwz9HxZCJDdiy6cf/Mj6vPxyYIs=
```

What did I do wrong? Why is my calculation of the hash value not correct? Is the initial string correct? If you manage to get the right result with the online tool, please let me know how it was done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR: It's the newlines**

Although some tools and programming languages, particularly those based on C or originating on Unix where C was heavily used, treat `\n` as a notation or representation for newline, that webpage does not. If I enter the string from your Q in the webpage's 'text' mode, it computes the HMAC of a value containing a backslash and a lowercase letter 'en', not a newline as required by the AWS spec.

If I enter the correct input (containing newlines) in hex as

```
4745540a656c61737469636d61707265647563652e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d0a2f0a4157534163636573734b657949643d414b4941494f53464f444e4e374558414d504c4526416374696f6e3d44657363726962654a6f62466c6f7773265369676e61747572654d6574686f643d486d6163534841323536265369676e617475726556657273696f6e3d322654696d657374616d703d323031312d31302d3033543135253341313925334133302656657273696f6e3d323030392d30332d3331
```

or in base64 as

```
R0VUCmVsYXN0aWNtYXByZWR1Y2UuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbQovCkFXU0FjY2Vzc0tleUlkPUFLSUFJT1NGT0ROTjdFWEFNUExFJkFjdGlvbj1EZXNjcmliZUpvYkZsb3dzJlNpZ25hdHVyZU1ldGhvZD1IbWFjU0hBMjU2JlNpZ25hdHVyZVZlcnNpb249MiZUaW1lc3RhbXA9MjAxMS0xMC0wM1QxNSUzQTE5JTNBMzAmVmVyc2lvbj0yMDA5LTAzLTMx
```

then I get the correct result (and you should too).